# Using a Java/.Net api from PHP

Tags: java, php, .net

I am integrating the Forex GainCapital API in my PHP code. But these API is only available in Java and .Net (I don't know both of them). Here is the link http://api.efxnow.com/DEMOWebServices2.8/Service.asmx. So, is there any way to get the data from a .Net or Java API from PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By looking at the link you posted, it seems like these are SOAP web services.

So you don't really use the actual API (the actual classes) but rather call a service over HTTP.

In php you can use [SoapClient](http://php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php).

Answer (score 1):

Did you try [PHP/Java Bridge?](http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/pjb/)

> The PHP/Java Bridge is an implementation of a streaming, XML-based
>   network protocol, which can be used to connect a native script engine,
>   for example PHP, Scheme or Python, with a Java virtual machine.

Comment: Well. But i don't know how to use that. Do you have any sample code to make the bridge?

Comment: @Udhay: I have never used it my self. There is an [examples](http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/pjb/examples.php) section which you could take a look at. I can't do much more than that.